# How not to send response to the client?

Tags: django, uwsgi

I'm trying to write Django app which will use uwsgi's websocket implementation. Came up with such view, basing on uWSGI's manual:

```
def live(request):
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(request.META["HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY"], request.META.get("HTTP_ORIGIN", ""))

    try:
        while True:
            msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
            uwsgi.websocket_send(msg)
    except IOError:
        log.debug("Client %s run away, ending connection..." % request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Everything is fine, but after closing page in browser will complain that view didn't return HttpResponse object. Ok, but if i'll return HttpResponse, later wsgi handler is going to rise IOError: headers already sent - which is correct, websockets from uwsgi are sending headers.

The question is: How to force Django to be quiet and don't send anything? Or maybe uwsgi has some functionality to cover this case?

Comment: `live` is Django view, right? I don't think you can use `uwsgi.websocket_handshake` in Django view. It should be used in [wsgi application](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application)

Comment: Yes, this is Django's view. BUt without handshake, done with uwsgi.websocket_handshake or my own handshakre implementation, i won't be able to use websockets. I don't want another server only for websockets. For now I have small patch to allow signal lower layers of Django that i don't want headers to be sent, and i think this will be the only way